# Swift: Mandrill POST Issue

Tags: ios, json, swift, mandrill

I am trying to send an email through Mandrill API.
I found below swift code [here](https://github.com/ashbhat/swift-ezJson) for JSON HTTP POST method:

```
func createRequest(myUrl : String, type : String, params : NSDictionary?, completion : (AnyObject?, NSError?)->Void ){
        var url = NSURL(string: myUrl)
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60.0)
        if params != nil {
            var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params!, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
            request.setValue("\(data!.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.HTTPBody = data
        }
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.HTTPMethod = type
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(),
            completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) in
                var returnedObject : AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: nil)
                completion(returnedObject,error)
        })
    }
```

Now I set my url and parameters like this:

```
let url = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json"
let to = ["email" : "xyz@gmail.com"]
let message = [
    "from_email" : "noreply@abc.com",
    "from_name" : "abc",
    "subject" : "Message through abc",
    "text" : "sample message",
    "to" : to
]
let params = [
    "key": "myKey",
    "message" : message
]
```

Then I call this function like this:

```
createRequest(url, type: "POST", params: params, completion: {(returnedObject : AnyObject?, error : NSError?)in
    if (returnedObject != nil) {
        println("data = \(returnedObject)")
    }
})
```

But I get error:

```
data = Optional({
   code = "-2";
   message = "Validation error: {\"message\":{\"to\":[\"Please enter an array\"]}}";
   name = ValidationError;
   status = error;
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at your validation error: **`"Please enter an array"`**. Are you sure you're entering an array?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes : I cant figure out what that means. In Maildrill documentation [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send)  "to" is key/value pairs as I am sending

Comment: Hmm, alright. Looking through the docs, I don't understand what's going on, so I'm gonna pretend I'm smart and go do something else. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!!! figured it out myself.

```
let to = ["email" : "kashif.izhar@gmail.com"]
```

should be

```
let to = [["email" : "kashif.izhar@gmail.com"]]
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Damn! What sorcery is this? :D
On a side note.. I will upvote this answer.. hope others find this helpful. Could you please explain (in the answer) where the misunderstanding came from? Were you wrong? Is the documentation of the API wrong?

PS: I'll upvote only after you update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the framework (or even the programming language) you are using, but the the response seems to be very clear.

Here's the thing:

> let to = ["email" : "xyz@gmail.com"]

This clearly doesn't look like an array to me, looks more like a dictionary (or equivalent in the language). I presume the following would work:

> let to = ["xyz@gmail.com"]

**Edit**

Perhaps, this would:

> "to": [
>               {
>                   "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
>                   "name": "Recipient Name",
>                   "type": "to"
>               }
>           ]

My next guess would be name and type are not optional.. and that the "to" field needs an array of dictionary items.

Comment: Just tried it and strangely the error message remains the same. In Maildrill documentation [here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send) "to" is key/value.